# Session variables disappearing

Tags: php, apache, firefox

I am finding that session variables are disappearing after about 30 - 90 minutes.  I check that the session has been started in the usual way before retrieving a session variable:

```
function chkSsn() {
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        session_start();
}
```

I am setting the session variables as follows:

```
function setSsnVar($nm, $vlu) {
    chkSsn();
    $_SESSION[$nm] = $vlu;
}
```

And retrieving them as follows:

```
function ssnVar($nm) {
    chkSsn();
    if (array_key_exists($nm, $_SESSION))
        return $_SESSION[$nm];
    else
        return "";
}
```

I tried adding the following lines immediately after "session_start", but it didn't make any difference:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I am using Firefox 48, Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) and PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php) might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your session data may be timing out within the client browser or on the server due to settings in php.ini.  The standard settings are: `session.cookie_lifetime` and `session.gc_maxlifetime`.  In fact, there are additional important settings that control session lifetime, so I highly recommended this [article](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/08/implementing-session-timeout-with-php/).

So create a simple php page that calls the function `phpinfo()` [PHP Manual - phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and that will output your php settings.  You should be able to resolve the issue from there.