# Laravel sessions - can a session variable disappear, while a user stays logged in?

Tags: php, laravel, session

First off, I do know that there's other threads about session variables disappearing. I've seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955635/session-variables-disappearing), for example. My question isn't just, can session variables disappear.

My question is about the relationship between a session variable, and a user's log-in session. In Laravel, I can get the current user by `Auth::user()`.

Is it possible that, at minute 1 of a users login session, I set a session variable, like `session(['x' => Auth::user()->id])` for example, and then at say minute 61, that user is still logged in, so `Auth::user()` is still returning the correct user, but now when I call `session('x')` that session variable has become unset?

Is the users login desynced from the `session()` variables? I thought a user was logged in through the `session` in the first place. But I'm getting situations where a user is still logged in, but some of my other custom session variables are disappearing, that's the context for this question. It has me very confused.

Comment: not sure if that is always the case knowing that a session can be persisted using different drivers i will create a test to see

Comment: `Auth::user()` isn't always use `session`. Based on your `Auth Driver` the mechanism will differ. Regarding your problem, I suspect that the session is expired but you are logged in because the `Auth` driver **not** using the session to keep track of your log-in state.

Comment: @BadPiggie that's a fantastic lead, thank you. Do you know how i can figure out what my auth driver is? Is it defined in the `.env` file?

Comment: Look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#main-content **Make sure you refer correct version of laravel, or switch**

Comment: I have this in config/auth.php:     'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',

Comment: Is it possible that each individual session variable expires separately? Or do they all expire in sync as a unit? @BadPiggie

Comment: No! As I know, `Session` expiration **cannot** be set individually, It is only possible for cookies.